# ECharts - How to zoom in to programmatically selected data?

Tags: echarts

I use Apache Echarts that plots timeline chart like below. I have a table below the chart, each row of which has details about a particular datapoint in the graph. The default zoom level of the chart is 20%.

Whenenver I select a row in the table, I want to highlight the selected datapoint in the chart and also want to zoom to that datapoint. I use select and datazoom dispatch actions for this, but I am unable to find the start and end of datazoom using the selected dataIndex.

How to programmatically calculate the zoom start and index using the dataIndex?

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `startValue` and `endValue` properties of the [dataZoom action](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.dataZoom).

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profile&code=G4QwTgBAJiAuIQLwQNoF0DcAoUkbwGEB7AVwDtYkIBGABm1wgGd4xYAVASwFsBTKgNRleAdwgAROLwAUASgbgIAYykBzImE68mVFAHIVsXurABPAIJ6ANBANqNpgELXbh4w4J7MORbFMAHbV0sCAgAbwgyED4ALlsAKQBlCAAJXhB_FyUiABsNOL0AYgB2ACMATiVeaj0IAF8rEPDI6N4C8SIlEj4KJizc_NtC0qgANjGlWoamiKjY2wA5IihtfrywApKAVigADmKAFinG0NnWgoAZThZeYTA-m2z1zd5aUqVi3eOZlvm9AHEAAoAVQgAFleNwHGtBkUoB9ivDvqdfm1bEDgTCNkNigAmUoAZlGuKmWG8AHpyRB_rdeGApBAoUoANbQOAgLBuExaJgAOgAZhoAKIgJQAC2k_PISlgnCIZAg0i5DhsnDIKwAHrJwk1GKUQExeFw-FQWOAODxeNhQoLINJGJwqPQII6ADxswikCgYF0CATasJNUKMPyBACSRm4VFD2hQYLgYt5YC9UGk8dgifp6qI3DkEAAVIqY3ycrdVBmIABaGiyWTeULBxRQEj02XyqjpzMptMJpMgbO57WFui0UfyIMekC8_wkJgSwMNhtzNExiOQ3nLk6LiCgHIkNEoNWamz6w3G3g2aSno2WiACZDN1tysiyGyPuDPtBbxecSOJPylnEC7bqEZAaNwIA5EBE4gU8gyrpGvJwWAMENnUqHoYudTjou17nneyCdkm3ZEVmUA5nmha4qOtA4fUWDYdgUpkDKz4QGAtwrGAa65v44DREwNgZJwAa6ooypmGG6q8BqVDCbyu77tItHWjuihmmwcn-JwSFEBoqYoPJikyNQr7KPYknSRqaB0YwnFaTp2T6dIhnaQpkFKbiZkSaYUmajZqmMGKvCcKoYqUMg8lMJwABeMgoLQNjUDZKDJQWEC0LyoyBYoHEyokYoZPwyC8OK5p8qo9L-GKnBKEhOScP4ABKpWwI4pgtTK0gTsBi4anEGmwAlX6oaYA2sENaXVsFoXhRAVK4t-DYiJwUAZnEnHDVWzATcNS2hDNYWwHEh3hRO0yLr1Db9RAfH0twfJOWAUCJKYfIavtEBjbd_EPbp-mvXypifSta1inEd0Cf9z2A7yoMZp9p3HT992PXpMNvbySPnU0dEcbALYKt1i55bABVFRAABklM6iBMYFKT1iobAWbRW2ZBxPoc5FV4n3c4EcSk-TgR8wBaJRWLcg46E47oUQ_js1QwGwHpOSyv40GLraEGwEY2LMax7bSJDD2iSB-OEyjUMQWAzJ0neVt_cuDt6AUDsm3yxkoASaAu4yfSqaEmH1FusqwIBtMNkYGrI3ogLJvynClkzi6lvysdVBQdJ6E0F2TgAWnp3Ccz1zMBGiehMA1XEp9uidq3SYLLBXIjpMyABiSd67Xi5zkQIiSPA5PkSIcT8pBhqfSrGsQAco6fTkIClLwOTt-BcB6wUOdYUtV2hPTthqtFKw9w29d603KwFK3IAd132fSxAI2hJVq2aw2SNxASo651uGrmBqa479QjcDVONc054lpMBUBHFm-4logEAUwC4S8V7ALPuvXWdIx7SkVvaSCZsQLsV4ATMACoiIQQ1MpGwu5tqDXPNqAQth_Z6EDmhR-ecLBIPQfgEAcQJI8l_k0Q0mhtAl0umXAWrhZwq24KfUIHFpLcUjILTidIeKfV_JCf8pgI57wbPLUUv5vqZV2BhT6txshX0jiBG6qUbC4mfkQkx5jUK8LiLwx-aAGLYCwFgbgpgCCFTYLyeU0gDANRZC4A27Nja_SYIQ7IZAWA7XNFQD2vJeHuT3LwVK9ZlDyhSfZZAGSsle0capAJQTzSZOuHxWA4pzCGzINIMIB89C8MLjmFwnSi5-RknERKqS2AADUPJokGjYTiYyckbXVIxBisggA):

```js
const start = data[dataIndex].value[1];
const end = data[dataIndex].value[2];
myChart.dispatchAction({type: 'dataZoom', dataZoomIndex: 0, startValue: start, endValue: end});
```